# How to edit data inside tables automatically created by hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

As I wrote in Subject. I have a table created automatically by hibernate, because of use this lines of code. ( @ManytoMany )

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long idMeal;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Map<Product, Weight> productsWithWeight;**
```

I want to create "patch" methods which should be able to edit data in this table.
Replace Product by other Product, and Weight by other Weight.
What I need to do ? 
Have You some good arcticles about how it works "underhood" ?

Comment: I think you're asking not about editing tables, but just manipulating data inside it, right?

Comment: exactly,  just corrected it ;)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your use case will be. `productsWithWeight` seems to be some joining table, but it makes no sense, because `Weight` seems to be a feature, a property of `Product`, so add a column `weight` to `product` table.

Comment: Aaah, now I see your point! :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I hope it helped you. I'd really appreciate also vote-up. Thanks!

Comment: Accidentally I was delete my answer to yor comment so I repeat it to the curious.  At every meal producst have a different weight. To make turkish soup you need 50grams carrot, to make coctail only 25grams.

Comment: I will back here to vote, when I will earn 5more reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cześć! :) `@ManyToMany` annotation is intended to map a relation between two different objects/tables. For example, you can have these entities:

A user that you can log in to your website:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
  int id;
  String username;
  String password;
}
```

And a role that a given user has (like admin, read-only, ect.):

```java
@Entity
public class Role {
  int id;
  String roleName;
}
```

There may be many roles in the system, and many users. Each user can have many roles, so we add:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
  int id;
  String username;
  String password;

  @ManyToMany
  Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

You will create some `CrudRepository` for each type, and save your user for example like this:

```java
//...
Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
roles.add(roleRepository.findByRoleName("ADMIN").get()); // <- maybe orElse() would be better, but it's just to show the use case

User user = new User(1, "SztyJkmajster", "password", roles);
userRepository.save(user);
```

At this moment you will have populated rows in `USER`, `ROLE` and `USERS_ROLES` tables.